# Exporting plural strings for localization

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xliff

I've defined pluralized strings using the [.stringsdict format as referenced here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/StringsdictFileFormat/StringsdictFileFormat.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH16-SW1).

I'm using XCode's "Editor > Export for Localization.." option to create XLIFF files suitable for translators and translation software, but the strings defined in `Localizable.stringsdict` don't get exported to the XLIFF file.

How is it possible to export these plural forms into the XLIFF format - get them translated - and import them back into the project?

I'm aware that XLIFF has no native plural markup, but the format [is extensible](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#Struct_Extension) so I don't see why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Can this possibly not be supported still?? My initial research tells me that stringsdict content is not in my xliff export (this is Xcode 7)

Comment: As this post is still getting clicked I should note that Xcode's XLIFF export now includes a stringsdict <file> section.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode automatically exports stringsdict (plural) strings only beginning in **Xcode 9.** I know, I know. Although stringsdict has been the way to do plurals in iOS and Mac for a few years now, Apple only half-heartedly supported it until Xcode 9. You can now also view stringsdict files in a format that makes them easier to read, including templates so you can add plurals with a couple of clicks. Xcode 9 and above can also view XLIFF files in a table format. Double-click on your XLIFF in Xcode to see. Before you’d just get the raw XML.

See here:
https://www.ibabbleon.com/copywriter-translator/2017/06/whats-new-in-localization-in-xcode-9-ios-11/

Comment: Thank you for this information. If only I had room on my laptop to install XCode 9 :-/

Also, I note that XLIFF 2.0 became a full ISO standard last November and still has no native support for plural forms.